# Err in android studio - using react native with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, react-native, gradle

i get this error in android studio,
i searched for this problem, but i couldn't solve.

> Gradle sync failed: Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
>                 The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.0,15.0.0],
>   [15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 15.0.1. Disable the plugin and check
>   your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
>                 Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (2m 35s 962ms)

app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
        transitive = false
    }
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' }
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
             // Google's Maven repository
        }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

I've checked the versions and they are the lasts. Help me please.